# C++/CLI iterator exception in try-catch-finally

Tags: exception, iterator, c++-cli, try-catch

In a try block I'm populating a std::list with new native objects.  In my finally block I'm iterating through the list deleting each native object.

I get an "Expression: list iterators incompatible" assertion when iterating in my finally.

I've created 3 test methods:

1. Method returns outside the try-catch-finally.  This runs fine.
2. Method returns inside the try.  Get exception when iterating in finally.
3. Method returns inside the try, but I removed the catch.  This was just something I happened to discover and can't explain.  But this one runs fine too.

Can someone explain what's going on here and the best fix?
I've uploaded [a very simple test solution here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1BdKBjxCl_nbEtMdHZQUDhRZDZSd2ZKY1VKU2UxUQ).

It's a VS2010 solution.  The app is a WPF app targeting 64-bit, but that could be easily changed if needed.

EDIT:
Here's the CLI code that demonstrates the 3 scenarios above.

```
int CLITryCatchFinallyBug_CLI::CliClass::Test1()
{
    // RETURNS AT END.  RUNS FINE.

    std::list<NativeClass*> nativeClassList;

    try
    {       

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            nativeClassList.push_back(new NativeClass(100,200));
        }

        // NOTICE RETURN IS AT END.
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        // Delete the native objects.
        std::list<NativeClass*>::iterator deleteIterator;
        for (deleteIterator = nativeClassList.begin(); 
            deleteIterator != nativeClassList.end();
            deleteIterator++)
        {
            delete *deleteIterator;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

int CLITryCatchFinallyBug_CLI::CliClass::Test2()
{
    // RETURN WITHIN TRY.  GETS EXCEPTION IN FINALLY.

    std::list<NativeClass*> nativeClassList;

    try
    {       

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            nativeClassList.push_back(new NativeClass(100,200));
        }

        // NOTICE RETURN IS HERE WITHIN TRY
        return 1;
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        // Delete the native objects.
        std::list<NativeClass*>::iterator deleteIterator;
        for (deleteIterator = nativeClassList.begin(); 
            deleteIterator != nativeClassList.end();
            deleteIterator++)  // WILL GET EXCEPTION HERE!
        {
            delete *deleteIterator;
        }
    }   
}

int CLITryCatchFinallyBug_CLI::CliClass::Test3()
{
    // SAME AS TEST 2 BUT WITHOUT THE CATCH BLOCK.  NO EXCEPTION.

    std::list<NativeClass*> nativeClassList;

    try
    {       

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            nativeClassList.push_back(new NativeClass(100,200));
        }

        // NOTICE RETURN IS HERE WITHIN TRY
        return 1;
    }
    // NOTICE THIS IS THE SAME AS TEST2 EXCEPT I'VE REMOVED THE CATCH
    finally
    {
        // Delete the native objects.
        std::list<NativeClass*>::iterator deleteIterator;
        for (deleteIterator = nativeClassList.begin(); 
            deleteIterator != nativeClassList.end();
            deleteIterator++)  // UNLIKE TEST2, NO EXCEPTION
        {
            delete *deleteIterator;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Rather than asking people to download a whole solution, can't you create a short but complete console app which you could post in the question?

Comment: If you're returning in the middle, then your std::list, scoped at method level, has likely already been cleaned up (it's destructor was called) by the time the finally block is reached.

Comment: Repeat after me: "This is C++.  I will use RAII for exception-safety and not try-finally.  I will use RAII for exception safety and not try-finally."

Comment: @ Jon Skeet - I've edited my post and added some code.
@ ebyrob - My std::list is constructed before the try, so I think I'm ok there.
@ Ben Voigt - RAII is new to me.  Perhaps I'll look into it.  Thanks.

Comment: I haven't gotten any responses since I edited my post with code. Can anyone make sense of what's happening?

Comment: Another week has passed.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm surprised no one is finding this problem as intriguing as I.  Why  Test2 and Test3 cause exceptions is baffling me.

Comment: Can someone verify they see this same behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the same problem in VS 2013.  It seems that the C++/CLI exception-handling implementation destructs native C++ types too early.  The exception only happens when there's a `catch` block and the `try` block has an explicit return.

```
const CString foo = "foo";
try
{
    return;
}
catch (Exception^ ex)
{
}
finally
{
    const CString bar = foo; // AccessViolationException
}
```

I tried to [report the bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) to MS, but apparently I'm "not authorized to submit the feedback for this connection."